# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:

Tags: xcode

I am using the the following code to upload posts to a wordpress site but have an issue.

```
  TallyViewController *postVC = (TallyViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)[self presentingViewController] topViewController];
[postVC publishPostWithTitle:timeStampLabel.text content:descText.text image:self.image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the error I am recieving...

```
[UITabBarController publishPostWithTitle:content:image:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157505dc0
2015-02-11 06:50:13.637 WingMan[966:160223] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController publishPostWithTitle:content:image:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157505dc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1853d659c 0x195adc0e4 0x1853dd664 0x1853da418 0x1852deb6c 0x100159c28 0x189bb9418 0x189ba252c 0x189bb8db4 0x189bb8a40 0x189bb1f94 0x189b8568c 0x189e2460c 0x189b83bf4 0x18538e9ec 0x18538dc90 0x18538bd40 0x1852b90a4 0x18e45b5a4 0x189beaaa4 0x10014377c 0x19614aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: The `postVC` you think you got is not a `TallyViewController` object, but a `UITabBarController` one. So either you try to find how to get it, or you have to give us the hierarchy you use for your VC.

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.  I was able to get the VCs to transition using...

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.  I was able to get the VCs to transition using... TallyViewController *postVC = (TallyViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)[self presentingViewController] tabBarController]; The problem that I am having is that the function that needs to run is not running...[postVC publishPostWithTitle:timeStampLabel.text content:descText.text image:self.image];